# Is there something wrong with my calculation of Gaussian binomial coefficients?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to find the number of bases of the vector space $F^2$ where $F = Z_3$.

I tried solving it using counting. For a vector space of dimension 2, there are three possible forms of bases:
$\binom{a}{0} \binom{0}{b}$;  $\binom{0}{a} \binom{b}{c}$;  $\binom{a}{0} \binom{b}{c}$

where a, b, c are nonzero elements of $Z_3$.
Then, there should be $2^2 + 2^3+2^3 = 20$ distinct bases of the vector space.

However, when I tried calculating using Gaussian binomial coefficients, I got the answer
$(3^2-1) \cdot (3^2-3) \cdot \tfrac{1}{2} = 24$, the 1/2 being there since the basis is an unordered set.

When I calculated the number of bases over $F=Z_2$, the way I solved it above and the Gaussian binomial coefficients yielded the same answer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: What about the pair $\binom{1}{1}, \binom{1}{2}$ etc? (They do not fit into your forms)

Comment: I knew I was forgetting something, for my mathematical knowledge pales in that of the great Carl Friedrich Gauss...Thanks gammatester!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First vector ($e_1$) can be obtained in $3^2-1$ ways (all possible vectors in $F^2$ minus $0$-vector). For the second - only $3^2-3$ (all possible vectors in $F^2$ minus 3 vectors collinear with $e_1$).